# How can I obtain a array subset containing an equal number of values from each interval (0.0,0.2),(0.2,0.4),(0.4,0.8),(0.8,1.0)?

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, floating-point, logic

How can I find an equal number of values from each interval from an array of floating-point numbers [0.0, 1.0)]?

For example:
1st Example
The Numbers are: `0.1,0.3,0.5,0.7,0.9`

and the Output should be: `0.1,0.3,0.5,0.7,0.9`.

Here element has been selected from each interval like for interval (0.0,0.2) = 0.1, (0.2,0.4) = 0.3 so on

2nd Example
The Numbers are: `0.3,0.5,0.7,0.9,0.5`

and the output should be `None`

Here no element is present for the interval (0.0,0.2). Hence the array subset has not filtered any values.

The Code I have tried

```
b = []
for item in a:
    if ((item>= 0.0) and (item<= 0.2)):
        b.append(item)
    elif ((item>= 0.2) and (item<= 0.4)):
        b.append(item)
    elif ((item>= 0.4) and (item<= 0.8)):
        b.append(item)
    elif ((item>= 0.8) and (item<= 1.0)):
        b.append(item)
```

But the Problem Here is the It doesn't satisfy the output of 2nd Example where if there is no element present in array for the interval [(0.0,0.2)] then it should print None Value.

What Should be Done?

Comment: I dont understand the question. Is this about finding duplicates?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You want to check for consecutive equal intervals (a1, a2, a3 where a3-a2 = a2-a1) and remove a3?

Comment: I have edited the post for better understanding of the question

Comment: As posted, the interval are `(0.0,0.2),(0.2,0.4),(0.4,0.8),(0.8,1.0)`.  From a decimal point of view, they overlap 3 values. Did you mean non-overlapping sets?

Comment: Yes I want non overlapping set

Comment: Instead of `b.append(item)`, use  `a.append(item), b.append(item), c.append(item),,d.append(item)`.  After the loop see if all have the same size, else "None".

Comment: It raises AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried it this way and it worked.

```
import numpy as np
val = input("Enter the Numbers: ").split(',')
a = np.array(val).astype(np.float)

b = []
for item in a:
    if((item >= 0.0) and (item <= 0.2)):
        b.append(item)
    elif ((item >= 0.2) and (item <= 0.4)):
        b.append(item)
    elif ((item >= 0.4) and (item <= 0.8)):
        b.append(item)
    elif ((item >= 0.8) and (item <= 1.0)):
        b.append(item)
for item in a:
    if((item >= 0.0 and item <= 0.2)) is False:
        b = None
    else:
        break


b = np.unique(b)

print(b)
```